# What does "taraboumer" mean?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, verbes, littérature

Louis-Ferdinand Céline writes in *Guignol's Band I* : "Des artistes qui **taraboument** dans Mile End à quatre heures de l'après-midi."
Does anyone know what "**taraboument**" mean? I couldn't find nor understand the meaning.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Je ne l'ai jamais rencontré, mais l'[œuvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line) contient beaucoup de termes d'argot et néologismes. Un homographe  du verbe [*boumer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boumer) peut signifier « faire la noce, la bombe » (TLFi), ce qui signifie « [faire la fête](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_f%C3%AAte) » [*to party*].

On ne sait pas ce que *tara-* viendrait ajouter. On connaît le verbe [*tambouriner*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tambouriner), jouer du tambour [*drums*] etc. qui se rapproche de *taraboumer* avec l'inversion d'une lettre (r pour m etc.). Par ailleurs le verbe rappelle un peu le nom *badamoum* (ou le verbe [badaboumer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/badaboumer), « faire badaboum »), lui-même peut-être élaboré sur le modèle de l'onomatopée [*patatras*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/patatras) (DHLF) ; il s'agit du bruit du tambour et de fracas, certainement du *tapage* [*noise disturbance*].

Par ailleurs on sait que dans [une traduction](https://books.google.ca/books?id=qD2B3hUXeZsC&lpg=PP1&dq=Guignol%27s+Band&pg=PA60&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=mile%20end&f=false), on a choisi « pianists » plutôt qu'*artistes*, et on a employé « *to raise hell* » (faire du grabuge, foutre le bordel), ce qui constitue peut-être un équivalent en langue anglaise et semble un peu aller dans la même direction que ce qui précède, mais ce ne saurait être déterminant.

Comment: Pour *tara-*, on peut évoquer *tarabiscoté*, *tarabuster* et surtout *taratata*.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une [onomatopée](https://dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9O0481) qui suggère un bruit dissonant.

La phrase pourrait s'écrire :

> Des artistes qui font du bruit en tapant sur toutes sortes d'instruments dans Mile End à quatre heures de l'après-midi.

Comment: Grâce à ton lien, j'ai vu la référence que Ac.9 fait au « Dictionnaire raisonné des onomatopées françaises », de Charles Nodier (1808) dans lequel on trouve [**tarabat**](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k123239j/f217.item.texteImage) que je n'avais pas identifié, et qui ferait peut-être de ta réponse la « bonne réponse » en fait.

Comment: *Ça m’étouffe. Mon guignol **taraboume** comme un fou. Il doit avoir la forme d’un poisson, déjà. D’ailleurs, un poisson n’a-t-il pas la forme d’un cœur ?* Frédéric Dard, *San Antonio, Un os dans la noce*, 1974

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Si on veut : *mon cœur bat comme un fou*: "Tara-boum, tara-boum, tara-boum..."

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Un cas de rétrécissement mitral peut-être... *il est possible d'entendre ce que les spécialistes appellent un roulement, correspondant à l'onomatopée de Duroziez : **Ffoutt-tata-rrou**. Ce terme créé par Duroziez imite les sons entendus à l'auscultation en cas de rétrécissement mitral, plus précisément de renforcement présystolique du roulement diastolique suivi d'un premier bruit éclatant, du dédoublement du deuxième bruit et du roulement diastolique.*

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie C'est peut être un peu anecdotique pour mériter une question...

Comment: @jlliagre réf: _Pourquoi tara- est utile là-dedans, c'est le battement moins prononcé que l'autre dans la paire ? Pourquoi c'est adéquat ou naturel ?_ Merci ! Bon j'ai rédigé une question différente mais qui traite de tout ça indirectement. Ici comme là, n'hésite pas à répondre !